# PHP crypt() function returns the same encrypted string everytime

Tags: php, encryption

I am doing an encryption with PHP and found this bug with crypt() when using with a SALT.

This is how I am using it.

```
echo crypt('hellow@stg', 'azraar'); //azbFcR.LdN/SM

echo crypt('hellow@stg1', 'azraar'); //azbFcR.LdN/SM

echo crypt('hellow@stg0', 'azraar'); //azbFcR.LdN/SM

echo crypt('hellow@stg2', 'azraar'); //azbFcR.LdN/SM
```

As you can see, the SALT I am using is, **azraar** and every time it prints **azbFcR.LdN/SM**

Link to `crypt()` doc, http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

I am confused with this behavior of PHP. It's very strange?

Comment: please, read the fine manual.

Comment: ...you even linked to it, you would just have had to read it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php:

> The standard DES-based crypt() returns the salt as the first two characters of the output. It also only uses the first eight characters of str, so longer strings that start with the same eight characters will generate the same result (when the same salt is used).

Comment: And to add: If you want a better hash, use a salt with a different format, like `$2y$10$usesomesillystringforsalt$` to get the Blowfish algorithm.

Comment: Thanks and what is most preferred then to use with crypt? is BLOWFISH the best one?

Comment: Is it usual to use the same salt ever time?

Comment: @mazraara That depends on the purpose  you want to use the hash for.

Comment: @PaulBrindley yes i am planning to have the salt as same for every password string.

Comment: @mazraara If it's about *password hashing*, then Blowfish is the most recommended option these days. But you will need a random salt per password! That's a must! See http://php.net/password_hash for a user friendly wrapper exactly for this purpose. Follow the link to the [userland implementation](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) for PHP < 5.5.

Comment: @deceze is having the same salt for every hasing string is fine ? i.e $2y$10$usesomesillystringforsalt$

Comment: @mazraara No, it's not fine. That's not a salt, that's a "pepper" and does not fulfil the same goal as a salt.